# How to update specific row for one column data in ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This is my grid

```
$scope.selectedUsers = {
      enableRowSelection: true,
      enableSelectAll: true,
      enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
      enableVerticalScrollbar: 0,
      columnDefs: [
        { name:'userName', enableColumnMenu: false, sort: { direction: uiGridConstants.ASC, priority: 0 } },
        { name: 'mandatory',cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox">', enableColumnMenu: false, enableSorting: false },
        { name: 'alternative user', cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-if="!$eval(row.entity.alternativeuserexists)" ><a ng-click="grid.appScope.showAlternativeUsers(row)">Alternative Users</a></div>', enableColumnMenu: false, enableSorting: false }]
  };
```

In the above grid contains 3 columns, 3rd column contains hyperlink , when i click link i want to update new value in 3rd column for particular row link value only not entire row data by using angularjs ui-grid

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite hard to understand, so if my answer doesn't fit your needs, try to provide more details or a Plunkr please.

You required a refresh of row-data on button click? Then read on.

You can modify your data-set dynamically and it will autoupdate your grid without reloading the whole thing.

I made a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/h4FLMhSUyqGNvjPhWnqu) showcasing a possible setup.
As you already did, one needs to provide a cellTemplate with reference to appScopeProvider. There you can create a function that modifies your present grid.data.

```
appScopeProvider: {
  showAlternativeUsers : function(row) {
    myData[myData.indexOf(row.entity)] = altUsers[myData.indexOf(row.entity)];
  },
}
```

Depending on how and where your new data arrives, you can adjust the update logic.